# Project won't build when settings.xml exists

Tags: maven, teamcity

Following on from [Unable to build maven project, pom.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059909/unable-to-build-maven-project-pom-xml-file-not-found), I'm finding that if settings.xml exists, the project fails to build.  However I need settings.xml to tell maven how to find the Oracle ojdbc6.jar file.

settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<servers>
<server>
  <id>build_server</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
</servers>

<profiles>
<profile>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>plugins-release</name>
      <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <id>artifactory</id>
</profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

The pom.xml is quite large (649 lines) but if the above settings.xml does not exist, the project builds but then fails the unit tests as it can't connect to the Oracle DB.  If the above settings.xml file does exist, the it can;t find artifacts in Artifactory that it does find if settings.xml doesn't exist.

The reposiories and distribution management section are:

```
<repositories>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>libs-release</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <snapshots />
  <id>snapshots</id>
  <name>libs-snapshot</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>plugins-release</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
</pluginRepository>
<pluginRepository>
  <snapshots />
  <id>snapshots</id>
  <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
</pluginRepository>

<pluginRepository>
  <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
  <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
  <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
  </releases>
</pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <id>build_server</id>
  <name>build_server-releases</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
  <id>build_server</id>
  <name>build_server-snapshots</name>
  <url>http://build_server:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I'm thoroughly confused and am hoping for some guidance.

build_server (not its real name) runs artifactory on port 8081 and teamcity on 8111.

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote?  At least comment so that I can either improve the question or resolve the build problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem turned out to be the ID's.  I changed the ID's in the pom.xml in the distributionManagement section to match the ID's in the pluginRepositories section and now it works.

I hope this helps someone else.